# find key of data.frame using repeat loop

Tags: r, loops, primary-key, repeat

I want to create a function that uses an algorithm to search for a primary key. The algorithm simply tests whether the first column has all unique values, if not, it tests the first and second column, and so on until there are no more columns. The output is "PRIMARY KEY (...)", where ... is the names of the key columns separated by a comma. If there is no combination that satisfies the condition, the output should be "PRIMARY KEY ()"

I have solved the problem for cases where the condition is met. When it is not met, an error is thrown, wheres I would like the output to be "PRIMARY KEY ()".

Here is my attempt:

```
get_key <- function(x){
  i <- 0
  repeat {
    i <- i + 1
    y <- x[1:i]
    if (!anyDuplicated(y)) break
  }
  return(paste0("PRIMARY KEY (", paste(names(y), collapse = ", "), ")"))
}
```

and an example data.frame that does not pass the test (i.e. "PRIMARY KEY ()" should be the output, not an error message).

```
df <- structure(list(char = c("a", "b", "b"), num = c(1.1, 2.2, 2.2
), int = c(1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("char", "num", "int"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below uses slightly modified test data to show three different cases. Following close to the original code but using a for loop instead of repeat. Note the `x[,1:i]` - omitting the comma means indexing the rows, not the columns.

```
df <- structure(list(char = c("a", "b", "b"), num = c(1.1, 2.2, 2.2
  ), int = c(1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("char", "num", "int"), row.names = 
c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

get_key <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    y <- x[,1:i]
    if (!anyDuplicated(y)) {
      return(paste0("PRIMARY KEY (", paste(names(y), collapse = ", "), ")"))
    }
  }
  return("PRIMARY KEY ()")
}

df
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
# char   num   int
# <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1     a   1.1     1
# 2     b   2.2     2
# 3     b   2.2     3

get_key(df)
# [1] "PRIMARY KEY (char, num, int)"
> get_key(df[1:2,])
# [1] "PRIMARY KEY (char)"
> get_key(df[2:3, 1:2])
# [1] "PRIMARY KEY ()"
```

Comment: thanks that works great. I used seq_along(x) instead of 1:ncol(x) as it is safer in case the user of the function provides an empty data frame. Also note that the comma is not necessary in y <- x[,1:i]. With no comma, the index is on columns...putting a column after 1:i indexes the rows

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to check all combinations of columns, rather than just `i:x` slices? Like e.g. this

```
get_key <- function(x) {
  ind_combs <- lapply(1:nrow(x), function(y) combn(1:nrow(x), y))
  for (i in 1:length(ind_combs)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(ind_combs[[i]])) {
      if (!anyDuplicated(x[, ind_combs[[i]][, j]])) {
        return(paste0("PRIMARY KEY (", paste(names(x[, ind_combs[[i]][, j]]), collapse = ", "), ")"))
      }
    }
  }
  return("PRIMARY KEY ()")
}
```

Comment: my algorithm is admittedly simplistic. The databases we (my company) create usually have the primary key as the first column, and if not that, some combination of the first and other columns. I think a better approach to what I suggested might be to 1. check the first and each other column individually; 2. failing that, check the first and each column cumulatively; 3. failing that, search for any other combinations that are a key, where the solution with the smallest number of columns 'wins'